# Wait for a background job in C

Tags: c, shell, background, jobs

I am trying to implement my own shell and I want to bring a paused background job to its running state but ,instead of background, I want to wait for that job to be done.

So far I can get, this resumes the job but does not wait until it finishes.

Here is my process a command function:

```
pid_t pid=fork();
if (pid==0) // child
{
      ...
      if(strcmp(command->name, "myfg") == 0){

            FILE *sp;
            char  proc[100];
            char *pid_comm = command->args[0];

            int PID = atoi(pid_comm);

            sprintf(proc, "/bin/kill -CONT %s", pid_comm);
            sp = popen(proc, "r");
            if (sp == NULL) {
                printf("Failed to run kill\n");
                exit(1);
            }
            pclose(sp);

            int status;
            waitpid(PID, &status, 0);
            // to check if it is waiting
            printf("%d\n", PID);

        } 
         ...
 }
 else
 {
    if (!command->background)
        wait(0); // wait for child process to finish
    return SUCCESS;
 }
```

I tested this command with `sleep 200 &` and this job has its own PID which I can get from jobs list. However, I cannot make the program to wait.

my command looks like:  `myfg <PID>`

Comment: What are you killing in child process ? You kill parent process ? If it is the case, your child become a Zombi process. What are you waiting in Child process ?

Comment: kill -CONT make a paused process to continue?

Comment: The process concerned by kill -cont was already stoped by : kill -stop ? Are you sur he is in stopped stat ?

Comment: oh yeah sure, I have another command which is 'pause <PID>' and it calls kill -STOP. I can succesfully stop and resume commands.

Comment: Use POSIX [`waitpid()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/waitpid.html) carefully.  And don't ignore the values returned by `wait()`; you need `int status; int corpse = wait(&status);` and then you test both the corpse (PID of the dead child) and its exit status.  Note that with `wait()`, there's no guarantee that the corpse will belong to the most recently launched child; there may be other processes that were run in the background that finish first.

Comment: but I want to wait for an arbitrary process, not especially for the child so using wait is not enough ı guess. Also, it is not waiting anyway, that is what I cannot fıgure out

Comment: Unix does not allow waiting for arbitrary processes, only child processes. The reason why your `waitpid` fails is because you `fork()` and try to wait in the child process, where the target process is a sibling and not a child. You should avoid forking first (this is also required for e.g. `cd`)

Comment: @HARUM SASMAZ, in this cas, you must use semaphores. The waiting process bloque on semaphore asking, and the releasing process (who call kill in your case) release semaphore

Comment: @HARUNSASMAZ maybe you are looking for [`ptrace`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/ptrace). Then, you can use `waitpid`.

Comment: @oxuf I checked ptrace, it looks like something related but I cannot figure out how to use it with waitpid